# Get signal strength PhoneGap

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

Using the below example from a PhoneGap app:

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)this.cordova.getActivity().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String result = telephonyManager.getLine1Number();
```

Can anyone help me out on what I am doing wrong in below code? I want to get the signal strength.

```
SignalStrength signalStrength = (SignalStrength)this.cordova.getActivity().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);         
String result = String.valueOf(signalStrength.getCdmaDbm());
```

Comment: maybe could you describe the issue you have?

Comment: Thanks for looking into my post, i am new to phonegap and i want to get the signal strength of the device with no lock so far, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so you're trying to create your own plugin for phonegap?

I don't think you can get the signal strength directly (unless you use android api 17).
You should setup a listener that stores the strength at each change, so you can return this value to javascript when you call your plugin function.

You can look at this android tutorial :
http://www.firstdroid.com/2010/05/12/get-provider-gsm-signal-strength/

Or you can have a look at the following post which seems to use a different method to read directly the signal strength : http://blog.ajhodges.com/2013/03/reading-lte-signal-strength-rssi-in.html